# Evaluating an integral involving Beta function ratio

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, gamma-function, beta-function

Does anyone have an effective strategy to evaluate the following integral? Is it perhaps some known special function?
\begin{align}
    & \int_0^1 p^x (1-p)^{n-x} \frac{B\left( y+sp, m-y+s-sp \right)}{B\left( sp, s-sp \right)} \,\mathrm{d}p \\
    = \, & \frac{\Gamma(s)}{\Gamma(m+s)} \int_0^1 p^x (1-p)^{n-x} \frac{\Gamma\left( y + sp \right)}{\Gamma\left( sp \right)}\frac{\Gamma\left( y+s-sp \right)}{\Gamma\left( s-sp \right)} \,\mathrm{d}p
\end{align}
Here $x,y$ are natural numbers, $n \geq x$ is a natural number, and $s$ is any positive number.

Comment: You neglected to tell us anything about $m$. Is it also a natural number? And is $m\ge y$?